# While validating today date with specific range of dates, shows inappropriate result in php

Tags: javascript, php

While selecting today's date as from_date, it shows "Not ok" message. Can anyone help me with this? I am using PHP.

```
$today_date = date("d/m/y");
$from_date = 01/04/2017;
$to_date = 05/04/2017;

if(($today_date >= $from_date) && ($today_date <= $to_date))
{
  echo("ok");
}
else
{
  echo("Not ok");
}
```

Comment: I'd read up on PHP fundamentals because you clearly don't have the basics down yet. You'll learn more that way compared to blindly asking the internet for help

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
$today_date = date("d/m/y");
$from_date = "01/04/2017";
$to_date = "05/04/2017";

if((strtotime($today_date) >= strtotime($from_date)) && (strtotime($today_date) <= strtotime($to_date)))
{
    echo("ok");
} else {
    echo("Not ok");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sachin PATIL